# SSDT Erro SQL71561 referência não resolvida

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

Criei um projeto de banco de dados para Azure SQL Database usando o visual Studio (SSDT). Por enquanto eu tenho apenas duas tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ServiceOrder]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY, 
    [Name] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ServiceOrder] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]) 
)
```

e

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QuestionsToServiceOrders]
(
    [ServiceOrderId] INT NOT NULL , 
    [Question] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_QuestionsToServiceOrders] PRIMARY KEY ([Question], [ServiceOrderId]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_QuestionsToServiceOrders_ToServiceOrders] FOREIGN KEY ([ServiceOrderId]) REFERENCES [ServiceOrders]([Id]) 
)
```

O problema é que eu estou caindo no famigerado erro:

> Erro SQL71501: Foreign Key:
>   [dbo].[FK_QuestionsToServiceOrders_ToServiceOrders] has an unresolved
>   reference to Column
>   [dbo].[ServiceOrders].[Id].   CloudEyeDatabase    D:\ProgramStudio\CloudEye\CloudEyeWeb\FASE0.0.0.1\CoudEyeDatabase\QuestionsToServiceOrders.sql  6

Fiz algumas pesquisas net a fora e descobri que é um erro comum para quem cria projetos de bancos de dados SQL Server com o Visual Studio. O problema é que pelo que vi, existe várias soluções possíveis, testei algumas mas não funcionaram. Existem outras possíveis soluções, mas honestamente nem testei pois nem sei se aplicam-se ao meu caso, pois meu taget do projeto é o `Azure SQL Database`. Algumas soluções eu honestamente não entendi como [essa](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a3d96dc2-dcc8-4eb9-ae0b-8226cc5aa232/ssdt-unresolved-references-sql71501?forum=ssdt) por exemplo.

Alguém já teve esse problema?

Se alguém quiser tentar reproduzir o erro basta criar um novo projeto (VS2017) do SQL Server (Outras Linguagens/SQL Server/SQL Server Database Project) e adicione duas tabelas que mostrei acima.

Comment: Eu ia apagar essa pergunta pois o erro é muito bobo. Mas vai que alguém passe pela mesma situação.
Na referencia da FK o nome da tabela está no plural `ServiceOrders` mas a tabela está sendo criada com o nome no singular `ServiceOrder`.